# FileZilla FTP server provides a help to commands even before user authenticates

Tags: ftp, file-sharing, file-server, filezilla

I have a Windows 7 computer running FileZilla server.  I was reading my logs a while back, and took note of an odd excerpt which I do not understand.

```
199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> 220 PlayNice in the SandBox
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> USER anonymous
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> 331 Password required for anonymous
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> PASS **********
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> 530 Login or password incorrect!
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> help
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> 214-The following commands are recognized:
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)>    ABOR   ADAT   ALLO   APPE   AUTH   CDUP   CLNT   CWD 
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)>    DELE   EPRT   EPSV   FEAT   HASH   HELP   LIST   MDTM
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)>    MFMT   MKD    MLSD   MLST   MODE   NLST   NOOP   NOP 
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)>    OPTS   P@SW   PASS   PASV   PBSZ   PORT   PROT   PWD 
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)>    QUIT   REST   RETR   RMD    RNFR   RNTO   SITE   SIZE
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)>    STOR   STRU   SYST   TYPE   USER   XCUP   XCWD   XMKD
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)>    XPWD   XRMD
(000199)10/28/2014 23:07:57 PM - (not logged in) (66.240.192.138)> 214 Have a nice day.
```

Without logging in, someone was able to get a list of available commands?

Is that normal?
Should I be concerned?
Is this preventable?

Besides banning the entire sub-net, what should I do?

Comment: Note that the "USER" and "PASS" commands are listed in that help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is perfectly normal. protocol does not force authentication in first place. even anonymous authentication is not required. Actually most of ftp servers are only for serving files. you should not consider that as a security flaw. you can try that with any ftp server out there. I don't think it's preventable.

Answer (score 0):

There are commands you need to use even before authenticating and you may need to get a help with them.

Obviously the `USER`, `PASS` and `AUTH` (for TLS).

But for example also `HOST` ([RFC 7151](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7151)). Which FileZilla Server does not support though.

Even if you use GUI FTP client, so that you do not care about help, the client may need to know what commands the server supports. That's particularly true for the `HOST` command. When the server supports `HOST`, the client needs to send that command before `USER`.

Note that the GUI FTP client would use `FEAT`, not `HELP`, but the consequences are the same.

It may be possible that the server chooses not to list commands in `HELP` or `FEAT` response, that are not allowed without authentication, before you actually authenticate. But the `FEAT` specification, [RFC 2389](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2389), does not state such possibility. So such server implementation might break some clients (which use `FEAT` before authentication, expecting a complete set of commands/features).